# Do I need *.egg-info directories when using setuptools/distribute to create a python package

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools

I have a "standard" python package layout like this:

- setup.py - using setuptools
- README
- src/moduleA
- test/

However, when I execute setup.py it decides to create the directory src/moduleA.egg-info.

The question is, do I need to worry about the contents of this directory and check it in with the rest of my code, or should I just rely on setuptools/distribute to regenerate it?  It seems that all the information in the .egg-info directory comes from the config in setup.py anyway.

Comment: I would also like to know where to get the official and clear introduction to this automatic generated .egg-info directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatically generated bits don't need to be checked in, unless you're actually *extending setuptools itself* as part of your build process.

However, if you're putting files of your own in .egg-info (like i18n resources for [EggTranslations](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/EggTranslations)), then those should definitely be checked in, since setuptools obviously isn't going to be able to regenerate them for you.  ;-)